# How change math font size in power?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fontsize

How can I change the font for power such a way that the power symbol is rendered much smaller than the number 3 in the following formula? I need to sum (necessarily with \displaystyle) was much smaller number of 3.

```
\pdfoutput=0
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage{concmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{displaymath}
3^{\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

which renders as

[image: Formula]

But it does sum in power too large. How to make, that sum was, for example, is 10 times less than the number 3? Or 5 times less than the number 3? The number 3 to make very large. And sum to make very small. Possibly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Have you thought of introducing a symbol, $S$, for the sum and writing `$3^S$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show your original, followed by two alternatives.  The first scales the summation to 20% of the original size.  The second scales the 3 to 500% of the original size.  The `\scaleobj` command is part of the *scalerel* package.  It is similar to the `\scalebox` command of the *graphicx* package, except that it defaults to math mode, and takes the current math style into account.

```
\pdfoutput=0
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage{concmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{displaymath}
3^{\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}
\end{displaymath}

\begin{displaymath}
3^{\scaleobj{.2}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}}
\end{displaymath}

\begin{displaymath}
\scaleobj{5}{3}^{\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use parentheses to make more clear what you would like to show:

```
3^{\left (\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} \right)}
```

[image]

Or standard in-line style:

```
3^{\left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\right )}
```

[image]

or even

```
3^{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}
```

[image]

This looks much more natural than having a huge 3 and a tiny `\displaystyle` formula.